# WHERE for filtering out data based on multiple conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I had a large table TBL_LARGE_TABLE with say 100 columns (column1, column2,...column100 all nullable) and my client gave me a query so i could filter out certain rows:

```
SELECT * FROM TBL_LARGE_TABLE 
WHERE 
COLUMN2='00123'
AND 
(COLUMN3 LIKE '%garbage%' OR COLUMN3 LIKE '%trash%')
AND 
COLUMN100='0';
```

Now, I want to put the data from `TBL_LARGE_TABLE` into another table `TBL_ANOTHER_LARGE_ONE`. What would be the best way to insert from `TBL_LARGE_TABLE`  into TBL_ANOTHER_LARGE_ONE excluding all the rows that will pass the above SELECT statement? I dont want to delete any data, I want the original table to stay as it is. I just want to select the exact opposite of the SELECT statement above.

Comment: How many number of rows are there in that table SELECT count(*) FROM TBL_LARGE_TABLE; ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO TBL_ANOTHER_LARGE_ONE 
SELECT *
FROM TBL_LARGE_TABLE 
WHERE NOT
(
  COLUMN2='00123'
  AND 
  (COLUMN3 LIKE '%garbage%' OR COLUMN3 LIKE '%trash%')
  AND 
  COLUMN100='0
)
```

Comment: I tried using NOT, but there are around 2mil records and when I add the count of WHERE (above condition) + WHERE NOT (above condition) i get around 1.9mil. I'm probably loosing some records due to NULL

Comment: `WHERE NOT
(
  Nvl(COLUMN2,'x')='00123'
  AND 
  (Nvl(COLUMN3,'x') LIKE '%garbage%' OR Nvl(COLUMN3,'x')LIKE '%trash%')
  AND 
  Nvl(COLUMN100,'x')='0
)`

This worked. Thankyou.

Comment: How can anyone know which columns allow nulls if you don't mention it in the question?

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO TBL_ANOTHER_LARGE_ONE 

SELECT *
FROM TBL_LARGE_TABLE 
WHERE 

  COLUMN2 <>'00123'
  AND 
  (COLUMN3 NOT LIKE '%garbage%' OR COLUMN3 NOT LIKE '%trash%')
  AND 
  COLUMN100 <>'0'
)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.